# Has Spider-Man ever wielded Mjolnir?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, mjolnir

Spider-Man is known to be brave, honorable, selfless, compassionate, and so on. Based on this, has he ever been deemed worthy to wield Thor's hammer (Mjolnir)?

Comment: You'll have to ask Odin

Comment: Why is this VTCed? Isn't Spider-man part of the same Marvel canon as Thor and therefore is quite plausibly can be found in a situation where he'd be in a position to find out the answer?

Comment: @DVK the questions isn't _has he ever held it_, it's _is he worthy to wield it_. Which would be an opinion based question / answer.

Comment: @Daft - unless I completely miss the canon (possible), the two are functionally equivalent. Short of trying to lift, there's no way of determiming worthiness.

Comment: @DVK - For the record, in at least one comic he's actually wielded it.

Comment: @Richard - does it matter that this question appears to be [lifted from another site](http://www.comicvine.com/spider-man/4005-1443/forums/can-spider-man-wield-the-mjolnir-615153/), 2 years ago?  Compare the wording of this link to the original wording of the question.

Comment: He could if he got a gold badge in a tag here.

Answer (score 17):

#### Not in the mainstream continuity. Spider-Man and Thor have rarely had an opportunity to meet on a consistent basis, let alone allow Spider-Man to have an opportunity to lift or use  Mjolnir.

[image]

In a non-continuity reference for **[Marvel Adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Adventures)** #40 Spider-Man is shown to be able to wield Mjolnir.

**Some of the fan buzz regarding the idea of Spider-Man being worthy:**

> In general, I think we can all agree that to be worthy of Mjolnir you have to have a heroic nature. Self-sacrifice, honour, desire to help others, that is all a part of the package. Describes a lot of heroes though, doesn't it?
>
> Spider-Man is certainly self-sacrificing, arguably even moreso than Thor. He lives by the adage "with great power comes great responsibility", and Mjolnir is obviously a great power. However, Spider-Man is more motivated by guilt than a purely altruistic nature, and I think that is what takes him out of the running to lift the hammer.

**REF: [Does Whatever a Comics Blog Can](http://doeswhateveracomicsblogcan.blogspot.in/2011/11/if-he-be-worthy.html)**

A non-continuity version of Spider-Man, **[Spider-Man 2099 - Earth #928 (Miguel O'Hara)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Miguel_O%27Hara_(Earth-928))** was deemed worthy enough to lift Mjolnir but never used the hammer relinquishing it to a Thor-empowered Steve Rogers.

> They successfully located Steve Rogers, in suspended animation again since the downfall of the Heroic Age. Having also located Mjolnir, Miguel worked with the Thor-empowered Captain America to restore order and prosperity to the world. When the Watcher alerted Earth's heroes to the Interdict barrier blocking them from the stars, Miguel and the others traveled out to destroy the barrier. The barrier fell with the sacrifice of Uatu, but Cap was sent hurtling through space with no hope of recovery. As his last act, he threw Mjolnir back towards his allies, and Miguel was surprised when he caught it.
>
> Although he was worthy to lift Mjolnir, Miguel did not transform while wielding its power. He eventually realized that meant he was to become a different kind of warrior and leader. Still, Miguel often used the hammer to solve arguments, offering anyone who disagreed with his leadership or plans for the future to lift the hammer if they thought they could.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pic of Spider-Man wielding Thor's hammer so I sure this answer the if he can hold it or wield it.

[image: Spider-Man holding Mjölnir]

Comment: This just looks to be a reprinting(?) of the comic mentioned in [Thaddeus Howze's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96543/82909), since [its cover image is the same](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Adventures:_Spider-Man_Vol_1_40).

Answer (score -3):

There are no criteria to wield Mjolnir. "Worthiness" is required, but that has never been properly defined. Really just to make sure that nobody can lift it unless it is required by plot convenience. So can Spider Man wield it? Nobody knows.

Comment: According to a comment by Richard, in one comic Spidey actually wielded Mjolnir. This would answer the question. If only we could find this comic :)

Comment: The comment really has no weight unless he posts a scan. No source I can find shows Spider Man lifting the hammer.

Comment: @RaceBannon - http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/9/96213/1832787-453099_ma__spider_man_40__page_14_by_david_nakayama_super.jpg

Comment: A context less page without dialogue, a universe, anything? Really?

Comment: Just found out that still is from the Marvel Adventures series which isn't mainstream continuity.

Comment: @RaceBannon - It's too late at night for me to do a proper job. Use gooogle images to do a reverse-image-search and you should find it with ease.

Comment: Anyone can lift mjolnir in space as demonstrated by red hulk and iron man. Moot.